# How to auto import new DAGs in Azure Data Factory Managed Airflow?

Tags: airflow, azure-data-factory

Once we imported files from a Container in Storage, it would make sense to auto import if any file is modified or excluded or if there is a new file in the Container.[image]

But currently this job is manually, so if I modify a DAG in the Container I have to go to Managed Airflow and do the "Import files" again and again.

[image]

Is there a way to set the auto refresh sync or an API to use to build an equivalent solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the import DAG REST API for automation:

POST https://management.azure.com/subscriptions//resourcegroups//providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories//airflow/sync?api-version=2018-06-01

Request body
{"IntegrationRuntimeName":"Airflow1","LinkedServiceName":"AzureBlobStorage1","StorageFolderPath":"airflow/","CopyFolderStructure":true,"Overwrite":true}

Answer (score 1):

To add to Abhishek Narain's correct answer, the DAG REST API follows the standard HTTP 202 pattern, so the headers of the response contains the "Location" URI that can be polled with a GET request for the status of the import.